# Logging in HapiJS v16 Models

Tags: hapi.js

I've created a HapiJS project, using my own MVC pattern.

When I want to log from inside my controllers in some cases. Currently when I want to log from my controllers I simply invoke `request.log`. I'm using Good as a logging plugin.

For example:

```
const user = function(req, res){
   // do stuff
   req.log(['info'], 'some log info here');
};

module.exports = {
   user,
};
```

How can I log from inside my models where I have no request object? I don't want to have to pass in my request object into the methods of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to register models as plug in, you will have access to the server object and so, you will be able to use [server.methods](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/server-methods)

EDIT

In my company we declare routes as plug in (see code below)

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {
  server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/FOO/BAR'

    handler(request, reply) {}
    });

    return next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'routes-foobar'
};
```

And we register as such :

```
server.register([
  require('./route-foo-bar'),
  ...,
]);
```

This way we have the server objects in our route
What I would do in your case is register my models as server methods and use them in my routes.

The same goes for logging.

I would register my log function as a server method and call them from inside my models

I don't know if it's the good way to do that but that's a least a working one

Comment: I'm using an MVP architecture. Thus I don't have access to the server object within each model. Do you have any elegant ways of gaining access to the server object in each model, or would it need to be passed in from each controller into the model?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it helps... If not, let me know